# Are there differences in how bindings are handled when using the bulk insert feature in ADF and SQL?

Tags: azure-data-factory

When using a copy activity and SQL Server connector in ADF pipeline, there are observed differences between how ADF handles a "bulk insert" operation and how SQL Server handles "bulk insert" when there are bindings on the table being copied into.

For example:

- On-prem SQL Server bulk insert command automatically populates an empty string for not null field if null in source, ADF cannot
- On-prem SQL Server bulk insert command automatically populates null in nullable datetime field even though source has string with spaces
- On-prem SQL Server automatically enforces bindings, however Azure SQL does not.

We tried the examples above in SQL Server using bulk insert and observed the expected behavior.

In ADF using bulk insert, the expected behavior was not seen

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify what 'bulk insert' you are using in SQL server. Bulk insert in ADF is [BCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) rather than an insert clause. If the 'bulk insert' you mentioned is not BCP, then they should be by design differences.